# Can I do this kind of Code Vectorization on iOS, and what are the alternatives?

Tags: objective-c, c, performance, ios, simd

I came across an interesting [blog post](http://altdevblogaday.org/2011/04/06/if-simd-o_o-or-how-to-vectorize-code-with-different-execution-paths-2/) talking about some kind of superb technique to speed up processing by "vectorizing code". It's very scientific.

He's using something called **SSE2** and also talks about **SPU**, and now I'm curious how this can be brought to digital signal processing on the iPhone.

Although this seems to be something I *must* deal with in the future, I wonder what the alternatives are. Some people told me it is possible to perform massive-parallel calculations on the GPU.

What options do we have to speed things up like this or even better? What frameworks and technologies are available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ARM CPUs on newer iOS devices have [Neon SIMD](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php), which is somewhat similar to SSE on x86 or AltiVec on PowerPC.

You might want to look at [Apple's Accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) which started out on Mac OS X but which is now also available on iOS 4.0 and later - this contains of a lot of useful routines which have been vectorized.

Alternatively you can try writing your own Neon SIMD routines, although this is not for the faint-hearted.